# CSS Overflow in Chrome 45 and Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow, microsoft-edge

In MS Edge and Chrome 45, using overflow:auto on one of my site's DIVs hides all the contents. I can resolve this by switching to overflow:visible. But why are these two browsers rendering differently, and how can I avoid the problem in my CSS?

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <iframe src="mysite.html" style="overflow:scroll;width:100%;height:500px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to tell when you haven't posted a single line of code?

Comment: Sorry, here's an example:

`<div style="overflow:auto;">
<iframe src="mysite.html" style="overflow:scroll;width:100%;height:500px;">
</iframe>
</div>`

Comment: @carston1998 Please share a link to a demo that shows the issue. You can stand up a quick one using http://jsfiddle.net or a similar site.

Comment: The example in your comments seems to work fine in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="overflow:scroll;width:100%;height:500px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is that every browser is different: Edge is from Microsoft and Chrome is from Google. They are not working the same because they are from different companies. You should read about SEO (Search Engine Optimization) and try to make your websites work on as many browsers as possible.